# check if string in df and if true apply df row to a new list

Tags: python, pandas, list

Im new to python and have an issue.
I have the below df:

```
language, count
en-US,12
en,5

lang_list = ['en', 'es]
```

I would like to check if the items in lang_list are in my df. If so, i would like to append the df row with the matched language to a new list.

This is my code till now:

```
new list = []
for x in lang_list:
  if x in df['language']:
```

Now, if true i would like to append the language and the count (taken from df) to my new list.
Can you please assist?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the first two characters from the `language` column exists in the `lang_list`, then filter `df` over those that do.
Finally, extract their `count` column and turn it into list.

```py
res = df[df['language'].apply(lambda x: x[:2] in lang_list)]
res['count'].tolist()
```

Example:

```py
language    count
0   en-US   12
1   fr  21
2   en  5

lang_list = ['en', 'es']

res = df[df['language'].apply(lambda x: x[:2] in lang_list)]
res['count'].tolist()

# [12, 5] # output
```